# Why does echoing htaccess-value end with file-ending?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created an htaccess-file to hide file-endings and prettify URLs. Now trying out everything I witness echoing a value from a prettified URL shows the file-ending in the result.

This varied a lot as I wasn't sure where the problem is. So there was `([0-9a-zA-Z]+)` for example. I have also tried solutions from StackOverflow.

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)$ viewevent.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And my viewevent.php-file

```php
<?
echo $_GET["c"];
?>
```

I used to try different variations, but it's either error or with the file-ending. And the URL I enter is: url/events/bino.
I expect `bino`, but I get `bino.php`.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules need more reordering otherwise in present state it will redirect `http://example.com/events/foo` to `https://example.com/viewevent.php?c=foo` thus exposing your internal handler.

Moreover you need to add `.php` for files that actually exist in your filesystem as php file.

You may use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/?$ viewevent.php?c=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. Put `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` at the end of the file, else it's kind of mixing with the other rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)$ viewevent.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```